# POST method returning 404 after form submission - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes, http-status-code-404

I am working on a E-Prescription Application using Laravel 8. I have built a checkout page which will submit a form containing only 1 value "appointment_id" so that after submitting the form by clicking finish the corresponding appointment status will be changed to "Completed" by the controller using the appointment_id. But when Im clicking on the button to trigger the methods it giving me 404 error. I have used POST method. CSRF is also used. Here is my codes ,

**checkout.blade.php**

```
 <form action="/doctor/appointments/checkout" method="POST">
    @csrf
       <div class="form-group row">    
            <div class="col-md-4">            
                  <input type="hidden" name="appointment_id" value="{{$appointment->id}}">
                  <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="SAVE">
                       
             </div>
        </div>

   </form>
```

some of my routes:
**web.php**

```
  Route::prefix('/doctor')->name('doctor.')->namespace('Doctor')->group(function(){
  //Appointment Routes

      Route::get('/appointments/all',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\AppointmentController::class,'AllAppointments'])->name('Appointments')->middleware('doctor');
      Route::get('/appointments/view',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\AppointmentController::class,'ViewAppointment'])->name('Appointment')->middleware('doctor');
      Route::post('/appointments/view',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\AppointmentController::class,'DeleteAppointment'])->name('DeleteAppointment')->middleware('doctor');
      Route::get('/appointments/conversation',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\ConversationController::class,'ViewConversation'])->name('ViewConversation')->middleware('doctor');
      Route::post('/appointments/conversation',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\ConversationController::class,'SendMessage'])->name('SendMessage')->middleware('doctor');
      Route::get('/appointments/requests',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\AppointmentController::class,'ShowRequest'])->name('Requests')->middleware('doctor');
      Route::post('/appointments/requests',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\AppointmentController::class,'RequestHandel'])->name('Handel')->middleware('doctor');
 
      Route::get('/appointments/prescription',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\PrescriptionController::class,'CreatePrescription'])->middleware('doctor')->name('CreatePrescription');
      Route::post('/appointments/prescription',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\PrescriptionController::class,'AddMedicine'])->name('AddMedicine');
    
      Route::get('/appointments/checkout',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\CheckoutController::class,'ViewCheckout'])->middleware('doctor')->name('ViewCheckout');
      Route::post('/appointments/checkout',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\CheckoutController::class,'EndAppointment'])->name('EndAppointment')->middleware('doctor');
}
```

**CheckoutController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Appointment;

class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    public function ViewCheckout(Request $request){
        $id = $request->input('id');

        $medicines = DB::table('medicines')->where('appointment_id', '=',$id)->get();
        $appointments = DB::table('appointments')->where('id', '=',$id)->get();
        
        return view('doctor.appointments.checkout',['medicines'=>$medicines,'appointments'=>$appointments]);
    }

    public function EndAppointment(Request $request){

        $id = $request->input('id');
        $appointment = Appointment::findOrFail($id);

        $appointment->status = 'Completed';
       
        $appointment->save();
       
        return redirect()->to('/doctor/appointments/all')->with('status','Appointment has been completed');
    }
}
```

I have checked my routes by

```
php artisan route:list
```

the route is existing there.
I have also cleared routes chaches  by ,

```
php artisan route:clear
```

still facing the issue.

I have also updated my composer. But thats not solved my problem. All other routes are working fine. New routes are also working except the only one :

```
Route::post('/appointments/checkout',[App\Http\Controllers\Doctor\Appointment\CheckoutController::class,'EndAppointment'])->name('EndAppointment')->middleware('doctor');
```

**

### Can anybody help me fixing this ?

**

Comment: `findOrFail` will throw an exception if it doesn't find a record which gets converted to a 404 response

Comment: @lagbox thanks :p I have done such a silly mistakes by naming the input field ''appointment_id' and requesting input as  ''id' .. that was the problem . Thanks buddy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "id" field is not `id` it is `appointment_id`.

`Model::findOrFail()` will throw an exception if it can't find a record which will get converted to a 404 response.

```
$id = $request->input('appointment_id');
$appointment = Appointment::findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because of the findOrFail: you are giving it an incorrect id, since in the form you sent the `appointment_id` but you only try to retrieve `id` from the request. Change it to:

```php
$id = $request->input('appointment_id');
        $appointment = Appointment::findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the code

```
 <input type="hidden" name="appointment_id" value="{{$appointment->id}}">
```

to

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$appointment->id}}">
```

Because id not found in CheckoutController

```
$id = $request->input('id');
```

Model::findOrFail If not found id it will throw 404 response

I hope it will help you